# Application.run doesn't work with module

Tags: ms-access, vba, ms-access-2010

I have two modules. In one module I want to run a sub from the other module indirectly. According to MS and a multitude of online ressources this should work - but it doesn't. What could be the problem?

```
'Module: "Helpers"

Public Sub ubTest()
  MsgBox "ubTest is called"
End Sub


'Another Module -> I also tried this from a form and a class...

Public Sub test()
  Dim s As String
  Helpers.ubTest             'works

  s = "ubTest"
  Application.Run s        'works

  s = "Helpers.ubTest"
  Application.Run s        'doesn't work

End Sub
```

(Obviously this is a test - in the real application I will have multiple modules and will not always have control over the procedure names - so I have to use the module-prefix)

I tried to /decompile and compact the database - no luck there either.

Comment: Maybe misspelling error? `s = "Helpers.ubTest"` in your question you have `s = "Helpes.ubTest"`

Comment: Sorry for the misspell. No, ot just doesn't work that way - but I havent yet found a proper solution. Just what I answered to HansUp

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The Access *Application.Run Method* help topic says this about the *Name* parameter:

*'If you are calling a procedure in another database use the project name and the procedure name separated by a dot in the form: "projectname.procedurename".'*

So I think when you supply `"modulename.procedurename"` (ie *"Helpers.ubTest"*), Access thinks your *modulename* is the name of a VBA project.  Since it can't find a project named *Helpers*, it throws error #2517, *" ... can't find the procedure 'Helpers.ubTest.'"*

Unfortunately, I can't find a way to do what I think you want with `Application.Run`.  I hoped `"projectname.modulename.procedurename"` would work, but that also triggered the 2517 error.

Comment: Thank you HansUp. I hunted for the error for over an hour. Apparently there are different help pages at MSDN one for office alone (where you find "word" in the path) and a separate one for access. The Access page says nothing about a module-parameter. (Although you find some accesss-resources on the web that claim there is one). I will resort to have a calling method in every module called `Helpers_CallbackRunner` which i then can call with `Application.run modulename & "CallbackRunner", SubName

Answer (score 0):

The answers of @HansUp and @Johannes (although I don't quite understand his solution) (and lot's of trial and error) lead me to this knowledge:

- Application.Run within Access won't try to use the first part of the procedurename (before the dot) as Module name, only as Project name
- Thus, the most important lesson, if you want to call a specific function name of a module through `Application.Run`, the function must be named uniquely in the whole project.

See the Microsoft docs:

- [Application.Run in Access](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/access.application.run)
- [Application.Run in Excel](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.application.run)
- [Application.Run in Word](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/word.application.run)

For example, two Modules that will have the same function `DoSomething` will always throw error 2517 when called through `Application.Run`: Access can't find the right function then.
You'll have to either rename (one of them) or create a wrapper function with a globally unique name for this goal.

So:

```
' Module1
Public Function GetName() As String

' Module2
Public Function GetName() As String
```

Should be changed to for example:

```
' Module1
Public Function Module1_GetName() As String

' Module2
Public Function Module2_GetName() As String
```

Or, add a wrapper for calls through `Application.Run`:

```
' Module1
Public Function GetName() As String
    GetName = "Module1"
End Function

Public Function Module1_GetName() As String
    Module1_GetName = GetName()
End Function
```

To test my gained knowledge, I made a wrapper function around `Application.Run` calls that, upon an error 2517, will replace the dot in the procedure name with an underscore and rerun, so the wrapper functions within the modules will be automatically called.
This makes the code more or less compatible with Excel `Application.Run`.
If you then create wrapper functions in your modules like my second example your 'good to go'.

```
Private Function RunApplicationFunction(Name As String, Value As Variant) As Variant
    On Error GoTo TryUniqueName
    
    Set RunApplicationFunction = Application.Run(Name, Value)
    Exit Function
    
    ' In MS Access we catch Error 2517 and try to call the function with the application/module name prefixed to it
    ' So WebHelpers.ParseXML becomes WebHelpers_ParseXML
TryUniqueName:
    If Err.Number = 2517 And Application.Name = "Microsoft Access" And InStr(Name, ".") > 0 Then
        Set RunApplicationFunction = Application.Run(Replace(Name, ".", "_"), Value)
    Else
        Err.Raise Err.Number
    End If
End Function
```

Answer (score 0):

After a long research I came up with a workaround that suits for me perfectly, maybe it works for you too.

```
Public Function RunModuleFunction(moduleName As String, functionName As String, Optional arg1 As Variant, Optional arg2 As Variant, Optional arg3 As Variant, Optional arg4 As Variant, Optional arg5 As Variant) As Variant
    Dim mdl As Module
    Set mdl = Modules(moduleName)
    RunModuleFunction = mdl.Application.Run(functionName, arg1, arg2, arg3, arg4, arg5)
    Set mdl = Nothing
End Function
```

Unfortunately `Appliaction.Run` has not parameters defined as ParamArray, in [definition](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/access.application.run) is optional parameters arg1-arg30. So you must use it as above and write them one by one.

For my solution 5 parameters is enough, but you can add more up to 30.