# How do you write a dynamic MS-Access VBA function call across multiple modules?

Tags: vba, function, ms-access, dynamic

I have a scenario where I have multiple modules that contain a "CreateMember" function.  I have a single Sub that makes a decision which module to call out to, however the dynamic call errors, stating that it was unable to find the Sub.

The line I'm running is

```
Application.Run (moduleName + ".CreateMember", param1, param2, param3)
```

moduleName resolves correctly in the debugger.  I get "Module1.CreateMember" but it errors out,

```
Error 2517, Microsoft Access cannot find the procedure.
```

Now, if I switch this to a non-dynamic call, it does resolve and work correctly.

CreateMember is defined as Public in all modules, so it's not an issue with that.

I'm wondering if qualified dynamic procedure calls aren't supported?

Comment: Try without the parentheses

Comment: Removing the parentheses doesn't pass syntax.

Comment: FYI `&` is the string concatenator in VBA.  You can often get away with using `+` but not always.

Comment: See also https://stackoverflow.com/a/21758357/478884 for module name vs project name.  You need `Application.Run projectName + ".CreateMember", param1, param2, param3`

Comment: Based on that article, the only play I have is to uniquely name CreateMember and drop the qualifier.

Comment: Yes that's pretty much it.

Comment: Why do you have multiple CreateMember functions? Maybe you should have one procedure with arguments.

Comment: Sounds like you're using modules as classes. Don't. Use predeclared classes instead, if you want a static class.

Comment: So the CreateMember is factory methods? On the Rubberduck site should be  examples  of a Factory pattern that  might help.

Answer (score 0):

Apart from the advice from *Erik A*, the closest you can get is:

```vb
Public Function RunCreateMember(ModuleName As String)

    Select Case ModuleName
        Case "Module1"
            Module1.CreateMember
        Case "Module2"
            Module2.CreateMember
    End Select
            
End Function
```

Comment: Wouldn't you also require the parameters for the modules?

Comment: @M.Johnstone: Yes. This is just a scheleton to illustrate the method.